# IsSearchable not recognized when creating azure search index

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cognitive-search, .net-4.6.1, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am trying to create index for for below model.

```
public class Booking
    {
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
        [IsSearchable,IsFilterable,IsSortable]
        public string BookId { get; set; }

        [IsSearchable, IsFilterable]
        public string BooknName { get; set; }
    }
```

Code to create index

```
 FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = new FieldBuilder();
 var searchFields = fieldBuilder.Build(typeof(Booking));
 var definition = new SearchIndex(indexName, searchFields);
 indexClient.CreateOrUpdateIndex(definition);
```

[image]

But this somehow ignores the `IsSearchable/IsFilterable` when I look at the definition and create the index with setting all this to false

Is there any other property i am missing here? I am using `Azure.Search.Documents - Version=11.1.1.0`

Comment: Did you make a spelling mistake? It looks like in the Booking class you have "BooknName" and your index is called "bookname".

Comment: Are you migrating from version 10 of the SDK? What namespace are IsSearchable and the other attributes coming from?

Comment: ah yes, I just created a small version of the class here. actual class is bookname and have lot more fields.

Comment: @BruceJohnston: I ma new to this, trying out brand new. its coming from `Microsoft.Azure.Search.Service, Version=10.1.0.0`

Comment: See Heath's response. You're trying to use attributes from the old SDK (Microsoft.Azure.Search.*) with the new SDK (Azure.Search.Documents), and they don't work together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're instantiating `FieldBuilder`, I assume you're using `Azure.Search.Documents`. In that case, you need to use the new attributes we added, such as `SearchableFieldAttribute`. The previous attributes effectively correspond to properties. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/search/Azure.Search.Documents/samples/Sample04_FieldBuilderIgnore.md for an example.

`Microsoft.Azure.Search` will soon be deprecated, BTW.